# Publishing Courseware on the Web

Tags: pdf, publishing

I have been teaching online courses for a number of years, using a home-grown system of html slides + narrative that works well for students using desktop workstations. That model is fading rapidly, and I am getting lots of requests for pdf versions.

Q: Is there a recommended collection of tools and a workflow that would publish pdf slideshows, syncronized with a narrative, as a pdf document, starting with latex source?

Comment: this question might be better fit for http://academia.stackexchange.com

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the `beamer` class along with the `media9` package in order to embed your audio and/or video files.